# Error while installing Node Js Legacy in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, nodejs

When I try to run this command

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

it gives it as

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package nodejs-legacy is not available, but
>   is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
>   missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>   However the following packages replace it:   nodejs:i386 nodejs

How to get a workaround from this? I can't find a proper fix anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nodejs-legacy package simply installs a symbolic link so that it can be executed using the `node` command.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: Hello it works but while installing it shows this on running second command`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nodejs' instead of 'nodejs-legacy'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1107 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
`     Like I need legacy one not nodejs

Comment: Literally all the `nodejs-legacy` package does is create a symbolic link so that the command `node` runs the command `nodejs` - if you're trying to install an older version of nodejs the "legacy" package doesn't do this.